# Modal and backdrop not showing on IPhone only (Angular 13)

Tags: html, css, angular, iphone, cross-browser

In our Angular 13 app, there is a modal component. In the component css there is this `:host`  selector for the root and is also the style for the backdrop:

```
:host {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Now, *Only on IPhones* (Shows ok on: Windows 11, Android phones) all of the component, the component root as backdrop (and all its content - the modal itself) are not showing at all.

Any Idea why?

Doesn't happen in other modals or in other components

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a weird one, and I'm not sure I understood everything, but it seems that the iPhone rendered the

```
:host { position: absolute }
```

differently that others. On absolute it renders the modal on the left side "outside" the iPhone screen:

[image: iphone renders outside of screen]

The "fix" if I would call it that was to change the position to `fixed`:

[image: iPhone renders correctly like other devices]

If you have an explanation for this phenomena I'd love to hear it!